# Can subclass object only inherit certain parameters from the superclass object?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, super

I have an abstract class Employee which is superclass of CasualEmployee. Employee has name, baseSalary as its parameter while CasualEmployee doesn't have baseSalary. Is it possible for CasualEmployee object to Employee object by using super?

```
public Employee(String name, double baseSalary){
this.name=name;
this.baseSalary = baseSalary;   
    }

public CasualEmployee(String name, double hourlyRate, int hoursWorked) {
  //insert super();

   this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
   this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;

   }
```

Comment: That is design-smell.  If a `CasualEmployee` does not have a base salary then it is not really a subclass of `Employee`.  Sounds like you need a higher level abstract base class that is the superclass of both. I.e. `Employee`, with subclasses `SalariedEmployee`, `NonSalariedEmployee`. There are other ways to approach this as well but addressing that would depend on much more data that what you've provided, and also would likely be too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: What he ^^^^^^^^^ said

Answer (score 0):

As said in previous comments, you have clearly a design issue. If you are going for an inheritance approach you should keep in mind that subclasses should be more **"specialized"** than their respective superclass! Therefore, all subclasses should inherit the proprieties from their parent class, add some or change the behavior of some others if necessary. But you should never end up in a situation in which a subclass should not have some attributes/methods from the parent class.
If it is the case this will break the **Generalization <-> Specialization** semantic principle on which is based inheritance itself.

In your example a solution would be remove the baseSalary from the Employee class and create another subclass (BasedPayEmployee for example) at the same level in the inheritance tree than CasualEmployee.

[Generalization, Specialization, and Inheritance](https://sourcemaking.com/uml/modeling-it-systems/structural-view/generalization-specialization-and-inheritance)